# JasperReport Server and JasperSoft Studio Configurations and Errors

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I have following questions regarding JasperSoft Studio and JasperReports Server (both community Edition).

I have installed both using installer on Windows Server 2012 machines.

1. I have created reports using JasperSoft Studio Community Edition. I have also installed JasperReports Server Community Edition(My Studio and Server are on different machine). I am trying to publish report from my JasperSoft Studio Community Edition but I am getting connection time out when I am running Test Connection for my JasperReports Server .

   Is there any configurtions which have to be made at the server side ? Or am I missing some thing?
2. When I login to my Server and try to add new Data Source , I am getting a pop-up window with the following error.
   Exception thrown executing
   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.tree.TreeAction@2aa04763 in state 'getNode' of flow 'treeFlow' -- action execution attributes were 'mapempty'.
3. In order to publish report to the server from my studio , Is it necessary to make connection to the Redshift Cluster before publishing the report?

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue ,did you find a solution for this exception ??

Comment: Nope. I did not found any solution . I tried tableau instead of JasperSoft.